# How to calculate pi power 2 in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

```
equations = [
    Eq(N_bRd, X_c * f_y * A * gamma_M1),
    Eq(L_c, L * beta),
    Eq(N_cr, (pi) ** 2 * E_E * i / (beta * L) ** 2),
    Eq(lamda, sqrt(N_bRd / N_cr)),
]
results = solve(equations)
# results = solve(equations, [m_A,m_D,theta_c,theta_b,delta])
results
```

I am getting the following error with sympy
NotAlgebraic:

> pi doesn't seem to be an algebraic element

When I change pi to 3.14 it work just fine.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to make your code a [mcve]? Right now, you are not telling us where you import `pi` from. With `from sympy import pi` it works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Common [mathematical constants](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/mpmath/functions/constants.html#mathematical-constants) are defined in the `mpmath` module (a `sympy` dependency):

```
>>> from mpmath import mp
>>> mp.pi
<pi: 3.14159~>

>>> mp.pi**2
mpf('9.869604401089358')
```

From the `sympy` [docs](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/mpmath/functions/constants.html#mathematical-constants):

> These constants are implemented as lazy objects that can evaluate to any precision. Whenever the objects are used as function arguments or as operands in arithmetic operations, they automagically evaluate to the current working precision.